# How to do sum of dupplicate keys in python dictionary?

Tags: python

I understand that python dictionary doesn't hold duplicate values and will modify if there are any. My question is, how can we add those duplicate values together?

Here is my code:

```
class ChoreTracker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.chores = {}

    def add_hours(self, chores, time):
        self.chores.update({chores:time})

    def print_summary(self):
        for i, (chore, time) in enumerate(self.chores.items()):
            print(f"{chore}:", time)


tracker = ChoreTracker()

tracker.add_hours('sweeping', 0.75)
tracker.add_hours('laundry', 0.5)
tracker.add_hours('working', 6)
tracker.add_hours('mopping', 0.5)
tracker.add_hours('laundry', 1)
tracker.add_hours('working', 5.5)

tracker.print_summary()
```

My output:

```
laundry: 1
working: 5.5
mopping: 0.5
```

What I want:

```
laundry: 1.50 hours
working: 11.50 hours
mopping: 0.50 hours
TOTAL: 14.25 hours
```

working is duplicate key. and i want to add it instead of just modifying the value : working = 6 + 5.5

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

Check to see if the key exists first.  If it does, add the time.

```
def add_hours(self, chores, time):
    if chores in self.chores:
        self.chores[chores] += time
    else:
        self.chores[chores] = time
```

Comment: Or `self.chores[chores] = self.chores.get(chores, 0) + time` to make it shorter...

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what i was looking for. Didn't even think of putting a check first

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is tailor-made for, well, counting things.

```
from collections import Counter


class ChoreTracker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.chores = Counter()

    def add_hours(self, chore, time):
        self.chores[chore] += time

    def print_summary(self):
        for chore, time in self.chores.items():
            print(f"{chore}:", time)


tracker = ChoreTracker()

tracker.add_hours("sweeping", 0.75)
tracker.add_hours("laundry", 0.5)
tracker.add_hours("working", 6)
tracker.add_hours("mopping", 0.5)
tracker.add_hours("laundry", 1)
tracker.add_hours("working", 5.5)

tracker.print_summary()
```

Comment: In the case of adding one chore at a time, which executes `self.chores[chore] += time`, perhaps it would make more sense to have `self.chores` as a `defaultdict(float)` (or `int`). Having a `Counter` would be more useful if it was supplying a dict of chores to update the existing values (and no repeating keys in the new dict); then `self.chores.update(more_chores)` works better. But it's not a use-case for the OP. Also, I think `Counter` should be used for counting (whole numbers), not adding/summation.

Comment: @aneroid `Counter` has useful methods such as `most_common()`, and counters can be summed together, etc., if required.

Comment: Indeed, that's a nice benefit for using `Counter`s. I just hope there's no update in the future that mandates its values to be int's and int-subtypes. ie Counting vs Adding.

Comment: Btw, since you are putting a Counter, it fits well with doing `self.chores.update({chores:time})` like in the OP's code rather than explicitly adding. Then the only (minimal) change for OP is `self.chores = {}` to `self.chores = Counter()`. More consistent and concise usage.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there won't be such a backward-incompatible update to Counters.

Answer (score 1):

To make the code more Pythonic, I think you should use `dict.get`

```py
def add_hours(self, chores, time):
    self.chores[chores] = self.chores.get(chores,0) + time
```

For total, you can either use a counter or call `sum` on dictionary values:

```py
def print_summary(self):
    total = 0 
    for i, (chore, time) in enumerate(self.chores.items()):
        print(f"{chore}:{time} hours")
        total += time
    print(f'TOTAL: {total} hours')
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
sweeping:0.75 hours
laundry:1.5 hours
working:11.5 hours
mopping:0.5 hours
TOTAL: 14.25 hours
```